# How to add a Badge for an Icon in Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using the Icon and Badge from Ant Design. I want to add the Badge for the Icon:

```
          <VscBell
            size={30}
            style={{ marginRight: '10px', float: 'right' }}
          >
            <Badge count={5}>
              <a href="#" className="head-example" />
            </Badge>
          </VscBell>
```

I have `import 'antd/dist/antd.css';` imported and the Badge works without the Icon. The Icon is from reacticons and it is displayed properly. I want to add the Badge to the top right of the Icon. But it does not show at all when included in the Icon.

Answer (score 0):

Put them both in a View Tag (if you are react-native) or div
and then take this styles to the badge:

```
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
```

Something like this:

```js
<div>
  <VscBell
    size={30}
    style={{ marginRight: '10px', float: 'right' }}
  >
  </VscBell>
  <Badge count={5} style={{ position: 'absolute', right: 0, top: 0 }}>
    <a href="#" className="head-example" />
  </Badge>
</div>
```

Comment: The Badge does not appear at all if I use this style.

Comment: Are you in react or react-native? because styles are different.

Comment: I'm in React. Without the style the badge is visible. But when I add the style its not visible at all.